# Can I travel to other Schengen countries while the residence permit is processing?

Tags: resident-permit, schengen, italy

I'm going to live in Italy for a year, I already have the relevant visa. 2 weeks after arriving, I need to travel to Germany for 2 days and then come back to Italy; however I wouldn't yet have the residence permit, just the receipt of the permit and my visa. Would I be able to re-enter to Italy since I wouldn't be leaving the Schengen area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as your visa is still valid. I have travelled like this before. I had a Swiss visa and travelled to France without issues.